# Tool to rasterize large SVG files to PNG

Tags: vector-graphics, svg, image-conversion, png

Please suggest a tool to convert (rasterize) large SVG files to PNG format. I am getting lucky with Inkscape for small SVG files, however a 45 MB SVG file is not getting converted.